# How to continue navigation after changing screens - Skobbler

Tags: ios, objective-c, skmaps

After a navigation has started, user has an option to switch between screens.
There are two screens with two different maps - one showing navigation and another showing some POIs.

Whenever screen is changed, new delegates are set and [SKRoutingService sharedInstance].mapView is set to the map view of that screen.

Everything works fine, only thing that happens and I want to avoid it - when I go back to the initial screen, the navigation starts from the start again (I was testing this in simulation mode on an iPhone 6 so far).

This happens when I set delegate

```
    [SKRoutingService sharedInstance].routingDelegate = self;
```

If I don't set the delegate, on return to the main navigation screen, navigation will continue from the position it is intended to, but all the navigation delegate methods will not function.
However, if i set this delegate, navigation will start from the starting point.

How to avoid this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the "navigation" part is shared between all instances of the map - if you start the navigation in one instance, one you switch to another instance then you'll still have the navigation perspective. If you stop it in one view, it will stop across all instances.

What you could do is switch the map do 2D and enable panning - this way you'll still be able to interact with the map (zoom to your POI) and still have the navigation on. 
Something similar to what happens in the [demo project](http://developer.skobbler.com/support#download) in the "Car navigation UI" demo when you start panning the map (after starting navigation).

Comment: Yeah, I notice that navigation will continue on all instances, and that is fine. But the problem is that, when I switch between screens and set delegates. After I unwind segue to the navigation screen and set routingDelegate to self, navigation will start from the beginning location. If I don't set this delegate, navigation will continue, as I want it to, but I will be uunable to interact with delegate methods

Answer (score 0):

You could really ask this question better. It's hard to understand what the question is about on first reading.

Having said that, it sounds like you're using a 3rd party routing framework, and setting that `routingDelegate` property has an unintended side-effect (of restarting the navigation). To avoid this, I'd create a new object that should be the `routingDelegate` all the time. Then this object can notify any other objects that need to know about routing events. This way, you avoid the side effects that are triggered by setting the `routingDelegate`.